# Converting a road bike into a switchgear

Tags: rims

I want to convert my GT Vantara road bike into a switchgear. And im wanting to use the tires that came with it.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Jules. Can you tell us what you mean by  a switchgear?

Comment: Consider asking a question, rather than making a statement.  What's a switchgear in this context?  Is it a fixed gear or do you mean a single speed, or something else? 


Tyres are tyres and as long as they're not worn out should be fine for most usage.

Comment: Do you perhaps have it setup as a fixie & want to put a flipflop hub on it (to switch between fixie & single speed) & you have directional tires? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

If by "switchgear" you mean a bicycle with a flip-flop hub in the rear wheel, there are a few things you'll need:

First off, your bike will need [forkends](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/36/Horizontal_rear_dropout.jpg/220px-Horizontal_rear_dropout.jpg) or [sliding dropouts](http://www.somafab.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/soma_frame_analog_dropouts.jpg). These differ from normal dropouts in that they allow you to adjust the position of the rear wheel to take the slack out of the chain that results when you have a single gear and no chain tensioner or deraileur. This will also allow you to run differently-sized cogs on either side of your flip-flop hub.

If you don't have these dropouts, it's still possible to make a fixie/single speed bike, but your chain length will have to be *exactly* right, and you'll have to have to ensure your fixed cog and freewheel cog are the same size, otherwise you'll have to resize your chain every time you flip the drive wheel around, and that defeats the purpose of the setup.

If you have that, though, then you'll next need a flip-flop hub. You'll either need a brand new wheel, or you'll have to rebuild your current wheel with a new hub. You'll also need either a fixed cog and a freewheel cog, two fixed cogs, or two freewheel cogs. The classic setup is the fixed/freewheel combo, with the fixed cog for speed and the freewheel cog for cruising, hard climbs, or recovery rides.

Two fixed cogs would offer you the chance to have two gear ratios in case you need another for a different riding style without giving up the ride style of going fixed.

Two freewheel cogs gives you coasting ability on either side, and the chance to have two gear ratios.

For road fixies and single speed bikes, you'll want a gear ratio between 3:1 and 4:1. (In a 3:1 gear ratio, for every revolution of your crank, your rear wheel revolves 3 times.) Most people get chainrings with between 42 and 50 teeth, with rear cogs between 14 and 20. More teeth between the two gears means the chain will engage more teeth on the sprockets, which will reduce drivetrain wear.

If you're not sure of what gear ratio to start with, figure out what gears you cruise in on your bike normally. Keep the chainring from that gear ratio and look for a single cog to go in the rear.

It's possible that you'll need a shorter bottom bracket to keep a straight chainline with only one chainring, but there's a decent chance that you'll be able to reposition the chainring on the drive-side crank to avoid needing this.

You'll likely benefit from asking your local bike shop for help, since, while this simplifies the bike, is not always a simple process.

Don't worry though, you'll be able to use the same tires. Those are only dependent on the rims of your wheels.

Now, if that's *not* what you meant by 'switchgear', then I guess we'll be needing a little more from you.